# Cluster/Find similar Stochastic processes

Tags: clustering, stochastic-processes

I have a set of data points where each point corresponds to the realization of a stochastic process like the stock market data of a particular company over some period of time. Now consider that the set of points are generated from more than one stochastic processes. Is it possible to cluster data points generated from similar processes together? Or find which data points have been generated from similar processes?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Do you mean clustering time series of stock data where the goal is to find companies whose stock prices have similar process properties?

Comment: Let's take the example of a production line. Various measurements of the product are taken at various points in the line. Different products have different processes and thus different types of measurement. For example a chocolate might have a color measure but a toy would have a different measure. Given that there are multiple products in the data set, how do I find out products which have similar processes? They need not be the same but might have some similar properties.

Comment: I'm still not sure about what you want. But, there are some work on clustering based on the correlation between the processes, or the similarity of their distributions, or both. For example, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.07822v1.pdf Is it what you are looking for? If so, I have some other complementary and related material.

Comment: See https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.5194 and http://proceedings.mlr.press/v22/khaleghi12/khaleghi12.pdf